# Ruby + RMagick + base64 image + RGB conversion from GrayScale doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, color-scheme

I'm uploading base64 encoded image to a RoR application. When I receive the image, it has a rgb color scheme (correct), when I write the image on file to be uploaded with paperclip gem, the image color scheme change from rgb to grayscale.

Here is the code:

```
source = src.gsub(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/,"")
blob = Base64.decode64(source)
img = Magick::Image.from_blob(blob).first
img.colorspace = Magick::SRGBColorspace
img.add_profile "#{Rails.root.to_s}/lib/color_profiles/RGB.icc"
img.write(url = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{self.id}_logo.png")

image = File.open(url)
```

the img is correctly a RGB image, if I check the resulted created file:

```
identify -format "%[colorspace]" #{url}
```

the color scheme is Gray.

Additional info:
The uploaded image is all black with white text, if I upload same image with red background, the final image is correctly an RGB image.

Comment: Do all the channels have the same values? That is are all 3 channels the same? If so, then that is possible depending upon version of imagemagick and how the file was created. What version of ImageMagick are you using? Does the uploaded image look like the original. Assuming the original has color to it, does the uploaded version look the same or has it become gray.

Comment: hi, I'm using ImageMagick 6.7.7-10, the uploaded image is lighter than the original, for example, background #242424 (original image) become #303030 on the uploaded one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in ImageMagick 6.9.9.27 and 7.0.7.15 when reporting the conversion of a grayscale image to RGB PNG. Identify -verbose is reporting grayscale but the string format %[colorspace] is properly reporting sRGB as are the PNG tags. I have reported this bug. For example:

```
convert logo: -colorspace gray logo.jpg
convert logo.jpg PNG24:logo.png
convert logo.png -format "%[colorspace]" info:
sRGB


identify -verbose logo.png
...
Colorspace: Gray
...
png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 2
png:IHDR.color_type: 2 (Truecolor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand. Is your image a color image or a grayscale only image?

IM 6.7.7.10 was during a time that ImageMagick was changing from non-linear gray to linear gray and back again. And also had RGB and sRGB swapped. So you may have a version where gray was linear (darker than non-linear gray) or where RGB and sRGB were swapped. You can convert back to non-linear using one of the following (I do not recall which to use at this time). The other will convert from linear to non-linear. If I assume your input image was grayscale and not color, then try one of these:

```
convert input -colorspace RGB -colorspace gray result
```

or

```
convert input -colorspace sRGB -colorspace gray result
```

If it is not grayscale, but color only, then leave off the -colorspace gray in these commands.

I would urge you to upgrade if you can. You are well over 200 versions old.

P.S. It is also possible your profile is causing a problem. I don't know what the RGB.icc profile is. Is that an Adobe RGB profile or an sRGB profile.

Can you reproduce your problem using Command Line ImageMagick? If so, post the command line you used. Sorry I do not know Ruby or RMagick.

P.S. 2  Apart from the lighter/darker issue, if you are trying to convert a grayscale image to color, then you will need to specify the output as PNG24:name.png. That is the only way to force a grayscale image to report colorspace=RGB without inserting color pixels.

Comment: hello @fmw42, converting the image from jpg to png actually helped me change the colorspace from greyscale to rgb but still the color after the upload and the conversion is darker, here is the [link](https://imgur.com/a/Q7i9w) of the images. As for the RGB profile i'm using  [this one](http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter). The imagemagick command I use is the following: convert input.jpg -profile /path/to/sRGB.icc output.png

Comment: `@marco` The images you posted were both PNG. You say you started with JPG. But JPG does not allow transparency. Yet, your input grayscale PNG has partial transparency. How did it get the transparency. Your input PNG is reporting the wrong colorspace (as described in my new Answer), but the PNG chunks are reporting it as truecoloralpha RGBA. So in your conversion from JPG to PNG you have changed the colorspace already and added transparency somehow. Perhaps you should post your original JPG.